# Adding Filetype != filetypes

Tags: autocmd, filetype

I have the following mapping:

```
augroup MatchingQuotes
    autocmd Filetype noremap! '  ''<Left>
    autocmd Filetype noremap! "  ""<Left>
augroup END
```

Is there a way to set the Filetype to "everything except vim and markdown" ? If so, how could this be done?

My current solution is as follows but I'm not sure if it's the cleanest way to do it or if there's a better way:

```
" Matching quotes
let FT_IGNORE_QUOTES = ['vim', 'markdown', 'help']
autocmd Filetype * if index(FT_IGNORE_QUOTES, &filetype) == -1 | inoremap <buffer> '  ''<Left>| endif
autocmd Filetype * if index(FT_IGNORE_QUOTES, &filetype) == -1 | inoremap <buffer> "  ""<Left>| endif
```

Comment: Other than wrapping the right-hand side of the autocommand in a function, i can’t think of anything

Comment: Alternately, create the mappings globally (no autocommand) and then unmap them in ftplugins that dont need them

Comment: _"Alternately, create the mappings globally (no autocommand) and then unmap them in ftplugins that dont need them"_
In that case, it will remove them globally, IOW in all other buffers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `:h map-<expr>` instead of auto-commands.

```
let FT_IGNORE_QUOTES = ['vim', 'markdown', 'help']
inoremap <expr>' index(FT_IGNORE_QUOTES, &ft) < 0 ? "''<left>" : "'"
inoremap <expr>" index(FT_IGNORE_QUOTES, &ft) < 0 ? '""<left>' : '"'
```